# GreenCell PowerProof 600VA UPS not taking mains power

Tags: ups

I have a UPS that when on and plugged into mains power, continues to indicate no input power and running from battery. Is it a fault or user error?

Comment: Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there was a physical fault in the unit on opening, where the main power connection to the mainboard had come completely disconnected. Resetting the connector against its detent solved the issue and the unit now charges and works on mains power as designed.